# Weird issue with Tesseract

Tags: .net, vb.net, tesseract

I get this weird error when using Tesseract (in vb.net):

"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Here is my code:

```
  Try
        Dim T As New Tesseract
        Using O As New OpenFileDialog
            With O
                If Not .ShowDialog = DialogResult.Cancel Then
                    Dim B As Bitmap = New Bitmap(.FileName)
                    T.Init(Nothing, "eng", False)
                    Dim L As List(Of Word) = T.DoOCR(B, Rectangle.Empty)
                    For Each w As Word In L
                        MessageBox.Show(w.Text)
                    Next
                End If
            End With
        End Using
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be calling `Init` with the first parameter being `Nothing`, but it should be the path where the language files are located.

Comment: Thanks - I was reading that it, by default sets the path to the executable path, and it said to put Nothing, so I'm trying that. When I put Application.ExecutablePath() or manually link to the tessdata directory, the program just closes without any messages.